# How to treat an Array with two elements as-like a Hash key / value pair?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, methods, arguments

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2. I have the following scenario:

```
# hash_params.class
# => Hash
# hash_params.inspect
# => { :key1 => :value1, :key2 => value2, ... => ... }
#
def self.method_1(hash_params)
  hash_params.each do { |hash_param| self.method_2(hash_param) }
end

# param.class
# => Array
# param.inspect
# => [:key1, value1] # or '[:key2, value2]' or '[..., ...]', depending on cases.
# 
def self.method_2(param)
  logger.debug "Key   => #{param[0])"
  logger.debug "Value => #{param[1])"
end
```

Given outputs commented out in the above code, when I run the `method_1` then in the logger file I have the following:

```
Key   => :key1
Value => :value1
Key   => :key2
Value => :value2
Key   => ...
Value => ...
```

I would like to treat the `param` variable in `method_2` *as-like a key / value pair* (*not* as an Array), for example by making something like the following

```
def self.method_2(param)
  param do |key, value| # Note: This code line doesn't work. It is just a sample code to clarify the question.
    logger.debug "Key   => #{key.inspect)"
    logger.debug "Value => #{value.inspect)"
  end
end
```

? Is it possible? If so, how? What do you advice about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
def self.method_1(hash_params)
  hash_params.each do { |key, value| self.method_2(key, value) }
end

def self.method_2(key, value)
  logger.debug "Key   => #{key)"
  logger.debug "Value => #{value)"
end
```

Otherwise you can still pass a hash in param like

```
def self.method_1(hash_params)
  hash_params.keys.each do { |key| self.method_2(hash_params.slice(key)) }
end
```

**edit**: if you want a hash as parameter you could just do

```
def self.method_1(hash_params)
  hash_params.each do { |key, value| self.method_2({key => value}) }
end
```

Comment: I would like that the `method_2` "can" / "must" receives only `param` variable kind of `Hash`.

Comment: ... of course, I would like to make that if it is possible in a maintainable way; otherwise, your previous (not edited) answer was a better way.

Comment: what is not maintainable here ?

Comment: It seems that to treat the `param` as an `Array` (that is, by using `param[0]` and `param[1]`) is "more maintainable" ("more readable" and "less hacked") to me than your version.

Comment: if you want a hash, just transform the key/value to a new hash like my last edit.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Hash[]`:

```
param = [:key1, 'value1']
h = Hash[*param]
puts h[:key1]
```

Output:

> value1

Comment: There is another way (to accomplish the same) than using `Hash[* param]`. It seems do not "conform" to the [Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#syntax)?

Comment: @user12882 What's bothering you? Could you specify the section which says that `Hash[*param]` is a bad practice?